# How can I prevent a popup from opening in another desktop?

Tags: display, desktop

I'm using a Macbook Air with an external monitor (I finally converted from Windows, don't know what took me soo long ;-) ).

When I have a Chrome browser window open in the external monitor and click a link that opens in a popup, the popup will open hidden on my Macbook.
I can't find a setting to open it in the same window my browser is in.

A few times I even had a pulldown open in a different window. Weird ...

Comment: Normally the app should respect which display it is located on. Have you tested this inside of Safari?

Comment: I never use Safari but test showed that Safari does it right. Firefox doesn't. By the way, I'm using the WindowMax app. Is there a better alternative to that app?

Comment: I'm not heavily familiar with WindowMax, but at a glance, it doesn't appear to do much that could cause the issue. You could always test with it turned off. Back to the topic, though: If FireFox and Chrome are both not respecting window locations on external monitors, it has be concerned now about support for this from Google/Mozilla. Are these two apps up to date?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! WindowMax doesn't cause it, same problem when it's disabled. Yes, I'm on the latest version of chrome. I just happened again: I click a link when I'm on desktop2, it switches to desktop1 and I can see an overlay that some url is loading. I switch back to desktop2 and see the popup window. However it switches me right back to desktop1. I have to use the 4 finger swipe down to be able to select the popup window.

Comment: I'm having a really difficult time finding this issue with Chrome or Firefox in any searches. Outside of support forums specific to each app, what if you test this on another User account of your system?

Comment: Good question! I've had this happen several times and it's really annoying